# How to interpret Ubuntu's ON/OFF toggle buttons?

Tags: unity

I have the same question as another poster and his question wasn't answered.  It seemed like the people giving help didn't understand the question, so here we go again.  The original poster's question is below.

What does the OFF on an ON/OFF toggle switch mean?  Is it saying the function is OFF, or is it saying if you click it, it will turn OFF?  I find it confusing.

I don't care about why anybody designed it that way, I just want the answer to the simple question above.  I am that dumb I have to ask the question.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/262242/how-to-interpret-gnomes-on-off-toggle-buttons

Comment: We don't re-ask questions here. If you feel you can change the question so it is within the scope of this site, please **edit** it (yes you can!) and get it reopened. This new question will be closed for the very same reason as it currently stands.

Comment: if you look with the mind of an absolute beginner (as they call it in zen buddhism ) it is indeed confusing. so i wouldn't close this question

Answer (score 1):

If it shows 'off', that is the current state. If you click it and it goes from on->off, there you have it. It's now off.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

as you can see in the picture, orange = ON and grey = OFF

it's like the Latex philosophy: WYSIWYM - what you see is what you mean

it's definitely not WYSIWYG  ;-)

Comment: Now I get it, it also helps if one isn't colourblind :)  Frank and Aranjedeath, you've saved a lot of people from confusion, wish I could thank you, but I can't :)  Over and out.